# How to retrieve final URL in Postman test with Redirect turned on

Tags: http-redirect, postman-testcase

I wish to test the URL at the end of a series of redirects. With `Automatically follow redirects` on, this appears not to be possible.

I have a number of redirects when my `Postman` request is made and I would like them to be executed automatically, so I am not turning off `Automatically follow redirects`, but my test needs to check the final URL of the request:

```
pm.test("URL contains final addr", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.url).to.include("/Customer.aspx");
});
```

This question is very similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56763018/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-redirected-url-from-a-postman-response) however I need to still get the URL with redirection turned on.

How should I be retrieving the true, final URL after a number of redirects?